# Drawing a figure in advanced geometry.

Tags: geometry, circles, geometric-construction

I was not able to draw figure for a question.
Question was

> From a point of intersection of two circles, the lines to the centers of similitude bisect the angles between the radii of the circles.

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what they mean:

[image]

$C$ is the centre of similitude; $D$ is a point of intersection of the two circles; and $AE$ and $BF$ are radii through $D$. I think they want you to prove that $DC$ intersects angle $EDB$. But it could have been clearer.

(I don't even know whether it's true, but it looks plausible!)

Comment: Any references validating your interpretation of _similitude_ depicted in shared diagram ?

Comment: Ya I also drew the same

Comment: one more possibility is let common tangent touches the bigger circle at I and smaller circle at J angle can also be between AI and BJ

Comment: But I am not sure

Comment: @programmer: [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_center).

Comment: @KshitijSingh: well that was a waste of my time then...

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for providing the [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_center) for _similitude_

Comment: @KshitijSingh the segments $AI$ and $BJ$ are parallel.